# Create a reusable Bootstrap "collapse button" as a Java Tapestry component

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, tapestry

My project uses many Bootstrap "collapse" buttons to show & hide content. The structure is consistent, so I believe this is a good candidate to be turned into a component.

The structure looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#name_of_div_to_collapse">
<span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<div id="#name_of_div_to_collapse" class="btn_collapse"> 
Content to show and hide when the collapse button is toggled
</div>
```

I would like to turn the entire button into a re-usable component, but I can't work out how I could do so while specifying the necessary unique data-target #name_of_div_to_collapse for each instance of the button. Is this possible using Tapestry? Could I pass a parameter specifying the data-target name from the TML where I call the component?

Update:

I can now print the button with a unique data-target using the following code. What I can't work out is how to insert the span caret into the markup generated by the MarkupWriter.

TML:

```
 <t:frontend.CollapseButton dataTarget="literal:#check_cases_collapse"/>
```

Java:

```
 @SupportsInformalParameters
public class CollapseButton {

@Parameter(required=true, allowNull=false, defaultPrefix=BindingConstants.ASSET)
private String dataTarget;

@Inject
private ComponentResources resources;

boolean beginRender(MarkupWriter writer)
{
     writer.element("button", "data-target", dataTarget, "class", "btn btn-toggle pull-right", "type", "button", "data-toggle", "collapse");
     resources.renderInformalParameters(writer);
     writer.end();
     return false;
}

}
```

This generates the following output, which is almost what I want:

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" type="button" class="btn btn-toggle pull-right" data-target="#check_cases_collapse"></button>
```

But I can't work out how to insert the span caret inside the button HTML using MarkupWriter. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that MarkupWriter accepts nested mark-up. The final working code for the java class is:

```
@SupportsInformalParameters
public class CollapseButton {

@Parameter(required=true, allowNull=false, defaultPrefix=BindingConstants.ASSET)
private String dataTarget;

@Inject
private ComponentResources resources;

boolean beginRender(MarkupWriter writer)
{
     writer.element("button", "data-target", dataTarget, "class", "btn btn-toggle pull-right",    "type", "button", "data-toggle", "collapse");
     resources.renderInformalParameters(writer);
     writer.element("span", "class", "caret");
     writer.end();
     writer.end();
     return false;
}

}
```

Improvements & optimisation still welcome.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I solved by this:

```
button data-toggle="collapse" type="button" class="btn btn-toggle pull-right" 
data-target="#${check_cases_collapse_uuid}
```

where in java I put this:

```
@Property
private String collapsibleComponentUUID;

check_cases_collapse_uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```